# At least one student having same bithday as others?

Tags: probability

**Problem statement :** There are 20 student in a classroom. we need to find out the probability of the number of days when at least one student has same birthday as other?

I have done something as shown below:

- Let P(at least 1 student have same birthday as others) = P(X)
- P(no student share birthday with any one) = P(Y)
- N = 20

We know that $$ P(X) = 1 - P(Y)$$.

I also know that $$ P(Y) =  {\frac{365!}{(365-N)!}}* \frac{1}{365^N} $$

So I just need to confirm what that $$P(X) = 1- [{\frac{365!}{(365-N)!}}* \frac{1}{365^N}] $$

If above mathematics is correct that is it valid for any number of student who are having birthday on same days?

Comment: A bit consfusing - just to clarify : We are looking for the probability that there are $k$ days in the year at which at least two of the students have birthday. And as usual without considering the leap year and the assumption of equal distribution of the birthdays. Correct ?

Comment: Yes, we are not considering leap year and assuming of equal distribution of the birthdays.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  As an aside, $\dfrac{365!}{(365-N)!}$ has a nicer notation that I recommend: $365\frac{N}{~}$ following the notation of [falling factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) used by Donald Knuth and others.  That makes this $1-\dfrac{365\frac{N}{~}}{365^N}$.  (*I prefer to typeset this as `365\frac{N}{~}`*)